# Передача данных между двумя классами. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, классы

Проблема такая: в одном классе я получаю данные с сервера. А второй класс, вью контроллер, должен отобразить эти данные. Как это сделать я не понимаю. 
Нижу привожу пример метода класса, который получает данные.

```
 func receiveMessage(){
socket.onText = { (text: String) in
  print("got some text: \(text)")
  // PARSE JSON text
  let json = JSON.init(parseJSON: text)

  if json["localID"] == "" {
    self.message = Message.createWith(json)!
    // здесь нужно реализовать передачу данных

  }

}

  }
```

Отображать данные буду в TableViewController. Мне главное передать эти данные, а дальше я сам :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно например так сделать

Вот ваш вью контроллер

```
import UIKit

class MyController: UIViewController {

    private var dataModel: DataModel?
    var message: Message?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataModel = DataModel()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         self.dataModel?.receiveMessage()
         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                selector: #selector(updateData),
                                                name: Notification.Name.init("dataUpdate"),
                                                object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
         NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc private func updateData() {
         self.message = self.dataModel?.message
    }

 }
```

и модель которая должна отдать данные

```
class DataModel {

    var message: Message?

    func receiveMessage(){
        socket.onText = { [unowned self] (text: String) in
             print("got some text: \(text)")
             // PARSE JSON text
             let json = JSON.init(parseJSON: text)

             if json["localID"] == "" {
                  self.message = Message.createWith(json)!
                  NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification.Name.init("dataUpdate"))
             }

        }
    }

}
```

теперь когда отработает метод receiveMessage() он сохранит переменную message у себя и отправит уведомление контроллеру который вызовет метод updateData и запишет переменную себе (ну или сделает с ней все что будет нужно, обновит тейблвью и т.д.)

---

Или можно написать через делегат

контроллер:

```
import UIKit

class MyController: UIViewController, DataDelegate {

     private var dataModel: DataModel?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.dataModel = DataModel()
     }

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(animated)
         self.dataModel?.delegate = self
         self.dataModel?.receiveMessage()
     }

     override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
         self.dataModel?.delegate = nil
     }

     func updateData(_ message: Message) {
         // some action
     }

}
```

протокол:

```
protocol DataDelegate {

    func updateData(_ message: Message)

}
```

модель для данных:

```
class DataModel {

    var message: Message?
    var delegate: (Any & DataDelegate)? = nil

    func receiveMessage(){
        socket.onText = { [unowned self] (text: String) in
             print("got some text: \(text)")
             // PARSE JSON text
             let json = JSON.init(parseJSON: text)

             if json["localID"] == "" {
                 self.message = Message.createWith(json)!
                 if self.delegate != nil {
                     self.delegate?.updateData(self.message)
                 }
             }

         }
    }

}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, не вызывается метод updateData во ViewController. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Каким способом ?

Comment: делал делегатом, исправил свою ошибку

Comment: так заработало ?

Comment: да, все заработало, спасибо большое.